# Academic literature on the construction of dangerous things

Tags: publications

I'm sitting at some boring ethics lecture and was surprised that few academics worked with formally classified or otherwise dangerous information.

I'm curious how this knowledge is published, stored, and disseminated *in practice*.

A few ideas come to mind:

- Research on the blast radius of munitions
- Imaging and communication systems for military hardware
- Culture of pathogens such as Anthrax

What happens if your research was commissioned by the DoD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a PhD thesis be confidential?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68204/can-a-phd-thesis-be-confidential)

Comment: @Ric Hi Rick, this isn't limited to PhDs, it also includes publications and venues for this work in general. For example, this there a `Nature Classified Communications` ?

Comment: Many institutions have a requirement that research conducted there be open, not secret.  [Here](http://theuniversityfaculty.cornell.edu/handbook/RESEARCHPOLICIES.pdf) is Cornell's policy: "Given the open nature of Cornell University, research projects which do not 
permit the free and open publication, presentation, or discussion of results 
are not acceptable. [...]  [R]esearch which is confidential 
to the sponsor or which is classified for security purposes is not permitted 
at Cornell University."

Comment: Usually such research would not be conducted at universities or published in the open literature.  It would be conducted within a government or military institute; their results might be "published" in internal communications, but that would be subject to the organization's internal rules.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi Nate, thanks for the info. It might be good to put it as a formal answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Historically Nazi rocket scientist Wernher von Braun had a thesis on munitions, only part of which was classified (see Wikipedia). Not sure if this is modern approach.

Comment: @Mikhail Your question ends with "What happens if your student's PhD thesis was commissioned by the DoD?" You might want to update it to include other work if you're interested in that.

Comment: In my field (communication networks), there is a major conference that has both "open" sessions/proceedings and export controlled or classified sessions/proceedings. See [MILCOM](http://events.afcea.org/milcom16/public/enter.aspx).

Comment: The specific question that is being asked here is unclear to me, however, Perhaps you can [edit] your post to clarify (in particular: to specify in the title what your question _is_, not just what it is about.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the US Department of Defense there is the [Defense Technical Information Center (DTIC)](http://www.dtic.mil/whs/directives/index.html). It is like PubMed Central but for DoD documents. Some of the content has been cleared for public release and is open to the public. Much of the content, however, has not been cleared for public release and access is controlled by a DoD employees [common access card (CAC)](http://www.cac.mil) and the network that DTIC is being accessed from. Not cleared for public release is not the same as classified/secret/top secret. Access to classified material is again CAC controlled and requires a dedicated computer on a protected network. I think, but am not sure, that DTIC is the gateway to much of the classified literature within the classified network.